# Search icon has white background in dark mode search help docs

Tags: bug, design, help-center, dark-mode

[image: a screenshot of the search help documentation in dark mode, but the search icon has a white background]

The search icon in the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) has a white background. It might fit in better if it used the dark mode icon on the dark background.

There's no accessibility issues since it has good contrast still.